# Passing the value from a few text fields into a third (generating a username) HTML, JS

Tags: javascript, html, textfield, getelementbyid

So a trying to pass the values from two text field to the third and I know it should be correct but it won't work. Would you know where is the problem? Thanks

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="ime">Ime:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ime" name="ime">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="prezime">Prezime:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prezime" name="prezime">
</div>


<div class="form-group">
  <label for="username">Username:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" onclick="kreiraj_username()">
</div>

<script>
  function kreiraj_username() {
    var ime = document.getElementById("ime").value.toLowerCase();
    var prezime = document.getElementById("prezime").value.toLowerCase();
    //   var id_clan = document.getElementById("id_clan").value;
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value.toLowerCase();
    username = ime + prezime;

  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign to the *value* of the `username` element, because primitive values are not passed by reference in Javascript. If you assign a variable to a primitive taken from an object, in order to update the object after changing the variable, you need to explicitly assign the the object's property again.

But in this case, since the original `username` value isn't being used, just assign to the field's `value` directly:

```js
function kreiraj_username() {
  var ime = document.getElementById("ime").value.toLowerCase();
  var prezime = document.getElementById("prezime").value.toLowerCase();
  document.getElementById("username").value = ime + prezime;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="ime">Ime:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ime" name="ime">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="prezime">Prezime:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prezime" name="prezime">
</div>


<div class="form-group">
  <label for="username">Username:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" onclick="kreiraj_username()">
</div>
```

Comment: When answers solve the problem you're having, consider upvoting and Accepting them to indicate that the issue is resolved

Comment: Yes but I don't have reputation for doing so

Comment: You are the asker of the question - you don't need any permission or reputation to Accept an answer to your own question.